# Преобразование массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json, преобразование, json-encode

Есть такой код:

```
  $query_sub = "SELECT id, item_id, status FROM main_table";                                        
  $result = mysqli_query($link_sub, $query_sub);                                                  

  $storage = mysqli_fetch_alls($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);                                              


  header('Content-Type: application/json');                                                           
  echo json_encode($storage);
```

В выводе json получается такая структура:

```
{
    "storage": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "item_id": "382362",
            "status": "none"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "item_id": "214647",
            status": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как преобразовать массив $storage, что-бы на выходе получалась такая json структура:

```
{

   "storage": {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "item_id": "382362",
            "status": "none"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "2",
            "item_id": "214647",
            "status": "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее Огромное Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в mysqli придется перебирать массив руками в цикле, а в PDO есть готовый функционал.

```
$query = "SELECT id, item_id, status FROM main_table";
$storage = $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['storage' => $storage]);
```

Переменную $pdo брать [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)